# Django reverse is giving me some trouble

Tags: python, django

My problem is that when reverse is called it throws the following exception

Reverse for '/documentation/' with arguments '(3,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Here is my urls.py

```
url(r'^documentation/$', views.view1),
url(r'^documentation/([0-9])/$', views.documents, name='documentation'),
```

here my views.py

```
def view1(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
      profe = request.POST.get('value')

      a = value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
      b = int(a)
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('documentation', args=(b,)))

else:

    return render(request, "documentation.html", info)

def documents(request,valor):
      ...something...
      return render(request, "anotherdoc.html", ..something..)
```

and here is my template (documentation.html)

```
...
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for p in ps %}
    <tr>
        <td><button id="boton1" button type="submit" name = "valor" value ="{{p.idp}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">{{p.nombre}} {{p.apellido}}</button>
        </td>
        <td>algo</a> </td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
</form>
```

I want 127.0.0.1:8000/documentation/1 from reverse() but I´m having a hard time trying that

Thanks

(Edit with traceback)

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Pa\De\Nueva carpeta\ag\Ag\scheduler\views.py" in documentation
  82.         url = reverse('documentation', args=(3,))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /documentation/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'documentation' with arguments '(3,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: It looks correct. You should try to trim your example down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow further investigation from people here. Welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: The error says it looks for a view by the name `/documentation/` rather than `documentation` (note the slashes). Please provide the full traceback and the relevant code that's mentioned in the traceback.

Comment: Thanks both of you for yur answers, I just edited my question with the traceback

Comment: Is it your root urls.py or a sub urls.py in an app ?

Comment: @AntoineFontaine is the urls.py of an app

Comment: In the root urls.py, do you use a namespace when you're including your app urls.py? Can you add it to your post (or only the interesting parts if it's a long one)?

Answer (score -1):

Reverse uses the URL name and you declared the name as `name='documentation'` but we can see you are using `'/documentation/'` instead:

```
File "C:\Users\Pa\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\ag\Ag\scheduler\views.py" in documentation
  82.         url = reverse('/documentation/', args=(3,))
```

Change that line to `url = reverse('documentation', args=(3,))`

If your URLs are name-spaced (you would know this if you have another urls.py in which this urls is include()), you should use `'[namespace]:documentation'`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That line was originaly as you described (and now is that way again, I have the same line as the one I described in the question). When I copy the traceback, I was changing some things trying to get reverse() to work. Unfortunately with no success

Comment: @kamus_pc You will need to provide the traceback that relates to the current state of failure then if that is not the one, because the error you are posting about makes perfect sense with that line - perhaps the same mistake is elsewhere as well.

Comment: Just added the correct Traceback and added another view that I have in views.py Maybe is something there that makes conflict.

Comment: Explain the downvote? This is the only viable solution to the problem given the information provided.

Comment: It wasn´t given by me, I thank you a lot for taking the time to answer my question.